# Xamarin - Logout when token expires

Tags: c#, xamarin, jwt, token, .net-5

I have an Api hosted on Azure which I consume on my Xamarin Forms project.

I show the login page at the beginning and I check if the JWT token has expired but I also want to check that on each http method in case it expires while the user is using the app.

So I need to either show the user the login page and tell them to login again I have been searching how to do that I can't get it right.

Here is my `AzureApiService` class.

```
public class AzureApiService
    {
        HttpClient httpClient;

        public AzureApiService()
        {

#if DEBUG
            var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
            {
                ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (o, cert, chain, errors) => true
            };

#else
            var httpHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
#endif
            httpClient = new HttpClient(httpHandler);
            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        }

        public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string url, AuthUser data)
        {
            var user = await HttpLoginPostAsync(url, data);

            if (user != null)
            {
                //Save data on constants
                CurrentPropertiesService.SaveUser(user);
                return user.Token;
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        // Generic Get Method
        public async Task<T> HttpGetAsync<T>(string url, string token)
        {
            T result = default(T);

            try
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(url).Result;
                HttpContent content = response.Content;

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var jsonResponse = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResponse);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (IsExpired(token))
                    {
                        await Logout();
                    }

                    throw new Exception(((int)response.StatusCode).ToString() + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnError(ex.ToString());
            }

            return result;

        }

        // Generic Post Method
        public async Task<T> HttpPostAsync<T>(string url, string token, T data)
        {
            T result = default(T); // résultat de type générique

            try
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);
                var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var jsons = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResponse);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (IsExpired(token))
                    {
                        await Logout();
                    }
                    throw new Exception(((int)response.StatusCode).ToString() + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnError(ex.ToString());
                return result;
            }
        }

        // Generic Put Method
        public async Task<T> HttpPutAsync<T>(string url, string token, T data)
        {
            T result = default(T); // résultat de type générique

            try
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                var response = await httpClient.PutAsync(new Uri(url), content);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResponse);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (IsExpired(token))
                    {
                        await Logout();
                    }
                    throw new Exception(((int)response.StatusCode).ToString() + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnError(ex.ToString());
                return result;
            }
        }

        // Generic Delete Method
        public async Task<bool> HttpDeleteAsync(string url, string token)
        {

            try
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                var response = await httpClient.DeleteAsync(url);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (IsExpired(token))
                    {
                        await Logout();
                    }
                    return false;
                    throw new Exception(((int)response.StatusCode).ToString() + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnError(ex.ToString());
                return false;
            }

        }

        // Login Post Method
        public async Task<T> HttpLoginPostAsync<T>(string url, T data)
        {
            T result = default(T); // résultat de type générique

            try
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResponse);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(((int)response.StatusCode).ToString() + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnError(ex.ToString());
                return result;
            }
        }

        public bool IsExpired(string token)
        {
            if (token == null || "".Equals(token))
            {
                return true;
            }

            /***
              * Make string valid for FromBase64String
              * FromBase64String cannot accept '.' characters and only accepts stringth whose length is a multitude of 4
              * If the string doesn't have the correct length trailing padding '=' characters should be added.
              */
            int indexOfFirstPoint = token.IndexOf('.') + 1;
            String toDecode = token.Substring(indexOfFirstPoint, token.LastIndexOf('.') - indexOfFirstPoint);
            while (toDecode.Length % 4 != 0)
            {
                toDecode += '=';
            }

            //Decode the string
            string decodedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(toDecode));

            //Get the "exp" part of the string
            Regex regex = new Regex("(\"exp\":)([0-9]{1,})");
            Match match = regex.Match(decodedString);
            long timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(match.Groups[2].Value);

            DateTime date = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddSeconds(timestamp);
            DateTime compareTo = DateTime.UtcNow;

            int result = DateTime.Compare(date, compareTo);

            return result < 0;
        }

        private async Task Logout()
        {
            CurrentPropertiesService.Logout();
            CurrentPropertiesService.RemoveCart();
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//main");
        }

        private void OnError(string error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[WEBSERVICE ERROR] " + error);
        }

    }
```

So you can see that in each http method I'm trying yo check if the token has expired already and then logout but it just gives an error.

On my `Logout` method I just want to delete all the properties and then navigate to the login page but it isn't working.

Please help I would like to know how to do this. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Trying to implement DelegatingHandler stops at `SendAsync`

Here is my `HttpDelegatingHandler` class

```
public class HttpDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        public HttpDelegatingHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            request.Headers.Add("Bearer", CurrentPropertiesService.GetToken()); 
            // before request

            HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

            // after request

            if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
            {
                await Logout();
            }

            return response;
        }

        private async Task Logout()
        {
            CurrentPropertiesService.Logout();
            CurrentPropertiesService.RemoveCart();
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//main");
        }
    }
```

Here my `AzureApiService` class

```
 public class AzureApiService
    {
        HttpClient httpClient;

        public AzureApiService()
        {

            var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
#if DEBUG
            clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                            (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
                            {
                                return true;
                            };
#endif
            httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpDelegatingHandler(clientHandler));
            httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
            httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
        }

        public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string url, AuthUser data)
        {
            var user = await HttpLoginPostAsync(url, data);

            if (user != null)
            {
                //Save data on constants
                CurrentPropertiesService.SaveUser(user);
                return user.Token;
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }

        // Generic Get Method
        public async Task<T> HttpGetAsync<T>(string url, string token)
        {
            T result = default(T);

            try
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
                HttpContent content = response.Content;



                var jsonResponse = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResponse);

                throw new Exception(((int)response.StatusCode).ToString() + " - " + response.ReasonPhrase);


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnError(ex.ToString());
            }

            return result;

        }
```

It works for PostAsync

```
// Login Post Method
        public async Task<T> HttpLoginPostAsync<T>(string url, T data)
        {
            T result = default(T); // résultat de type générique

            try
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                StringContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri(url), content);


                var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResponse);


                return result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                OnError(ex.ToString());
                return result;
            }
        }
```

But as I said it stops when trying to get data

Comment: Is the problem same as the issue in the lasted question?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes! I thought the problem was something else but it really is the one on the last question. I'll try what you said :)

Answer (score 0):

You can handle 401 Unauthorized response in a custom Delegating handler. This way you can handle anything before and after request execution in a single place.

```
public class HttpDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public HttpDelegatingHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Basic {0}", MyUserRepository.AuthToken));

        // before request

        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        // after request

        if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//main");
        }

        return response;
    }
}

public class AzureApiService
{
    HttpClient httpClient;

    public AzureApiService()
    {

     var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
#if DEBUG
        clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                        (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) =>
                        {
                            return true;
                        };
#endif
        httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpDelegatingHandler(clientHandler));
        httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        httpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;
    }
....
// Generic Get Method
public async Task<T> HttpGetAsync<T>(string url, string token)
{
    T result = default(T);

    try
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
        
        var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonResponse);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        OnError(ex.ToString());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this, so how could I implement this on my `AzureApiService` class?

Comment: It is a constructor parameter. Create a descendant class of Delegating Handler, instantiate it and pass it via HttpClient constructor parameter. In your case in AzureApiService constructor. I would personally take out the HttpClient logic out of your service and make it as a Singleton.

Comment: So sorry to insist, could you add the code for that? I tried it and now my app gets stuck. I'm sure I did it the wrong way

Comment: I'm having issues at calling getAsync() it stops and does nothing

Comment: Without a minimal working sample it is hard to provide a working example. I have edited the post and provided a blind implementation. Please, let me know. You do not need to handle each HTTP method separately. In your case your HTTP methods should only do serialization/deserialization which passes data from/into HttpClient methods.

Comment: Thanks but with the edited code it is still stopping at SendAsync. I will edit my code to show how I have it